# Hierarchical query for mulitiple groups

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to generate every month end date between two dates but I need to do that for multiple groups. Simplified example is here:

```
select last_day(add_months(date '2015-01-01', level - 1)), 1 gr from dual
connect by level <= 12
union all
select last_day(add_months(date '2015-01-01', level - 1)), 2 gr from dual
connect by level <= 12;
```

Can it be done in single SQL query without `union all` as I have many groups.

I know I can do it with `PL/SQL` but just out of curiosity it is possible to do with single SQL statement?

I'd like query like this one:

```
with d as (
select date '2015-01-01' start_date, date '2015-12-01' end_date, 1 gr from dual
union all 
select date '2015-01-01' start_date, date '2015-12-01' end_date, 2 gr from dual
)
select last_day(add_months(start_date, level - 1)) from d
start with start_date = date '2015-01-01'
connect by level <= months_between(end_date, start_date);
```

but generating results as first query does not `cross join`

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Query in question generates expected data but using `union all`. I'd like to get same data in single statement without `union all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `PRIOR` and `SYS_GUID()` option

```
WITH d 
     AS (SELECT DATE '2015-01-01' start_date, 
                DATE '2015-12-01' end_date, 
                1                 gr 
         FROM   dual 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT DATE '2015-01-01' start_date, 
                DATE '2015-12-01' end_date, 
                2                 gr 
         FROM   dual) 
SELECT gr, 
       last_day(add_months(start_date, LEVEL - 1)) AS dt 
FROM   d 
START WITH start_date = DATE '2015-01-01' 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= months_between(end_date, start_date) 
           AND PRIOR gr = gr 
                     AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL 
ORDER  BY gr, 
          dt 

| GR |                   DT |
|----|----------------------|
|  1 | 2015-01-31T00:00:00Z |
|  1 | 2015-02-28T00:00:00Z |
|  1 | 2015-03-31T00:00:00Z |
|  1 | 2015-04-30T00:00:00Z |
|  1 | 2015-05-31T00:00:00Z |
|  1 | 2015-06-30T00:00:00Z |
|  1 | 2015-07-31T00:00:00Z |
|  1 | 2015-08-31T00:00:00Z |
|  1 | 2015-09-30T00:00:00Z |
|  1 | 2015-10-31T00:00:00Z |
|  1 | 2015-11-30T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2015-01-31T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2015-02-28T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2015-03-31T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2015-04-30T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2015-05-31T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2015-06-30T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2015-07-31T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2015-08-31T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2015-09-30T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2015-10-31T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2015-11-30T00:00:00Z |
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/1017)

Comment: That's good. I've used only `prior` without `guid` and got data loop. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've found one more way but `lateral` is also not what I was aiming for. Kaushik's answer is what I was looking for.

```
with data as (
    select date '2015-01-01' start_date, date '2015-12-01' end_date, 1 as gr from dual
    union all
    select date '2015-01-01' start_date, date '2015-12-01' end_date, 2 as gr from dual
),
data_level as(
    select start_Date
        ,end_date
        ,gr
        ,months_between(end_date,start_date) + 1 as lvl
    from data)
select g from data_level,
lateral(select last_day(add_months(start_date,level - 1)) g
        from dual 
        connect by level <= lvl
);
```